# How do you create a "Class initiated" Event or is there one?

Tags: .net, vb.net, event-handling

I want to have an event that is triggered when a class instance is created. I would like to have this happen from within the class. I know I could just raise the event one line after the new instance code is executed, but that defeats the OOD purpose if you have several places where the class is re-newed.

I tried to raise event from `Sub New`, and that results in the trigger being fired, but the instance is not created at that time, so when the event handler fires the instance is `nothing`.

Comment: class can't be renewed. constructor runs only once. Bring some code

Comment: You'd have to declare a `Shared` event on the class that you can then raise from a constructor. Seems a rather odd thing to do though.

Comment: I used incorrect phrase. By Renewed, I mean to say, initialized. As in -  
Dim SomeInstance as new MyClass. 
Every time, that is called, I want MyClass to trigger an 'I WAS created event'. 
Meaning that by the time the event is raised, the instance is already created. Something like a Form.Shown event, if you take the class and form as being just an object for the sakes of illustration.

Answer (score 3):

Solution - use a factory method with shared event

```vb
public class MyClass
 
    public shared event SomeEvent As EventHandler
    
    private sub New()
    end sub

    public shared sub CreateInstance()
        Dim instance as new MyClass()
        RaiseEvent SomeEvent(instance, new EventArgs())
        return instance;
    End Sub

end class
```

Consume

```vb
AddHandler MyClass.SomeEvent, AddressOf SomeHandlerMethod

dim cls as MyClass = MyClass.CreateInstance()
```

`SomeHandlerMethod` will run before you get `cls`